# How to release the memory used to parse XML field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

I have opened a lot of large XML using the stored procedure `sp_xml_preparedocument`, and I close the tab on SSMS without calling `sp_xml_removedocument` to release the memory.

As a result, now when I try to parse another XML using following code:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @result
```

I get this error:

> XML document could not be created because server memory is low. Use sp_xml_removedocument to release XML documents

But since I did not store the handles, how could I release the memory held by the opened XML? The session has been closed, and I cannot get the handle anymore...

P.S. I cannot believe that if you call the `sp_xml_preparedocument` and forget to close it using `sp_xml_removedocument`, the file will stay in the internal cache forever. Is that real?

Comment: Use [`select document_id from sys.dm_exec_xml_handles(@@SPID);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-xml-handles-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to retrieve the handles.

Comment: @HABO Thank you! but I found out that even if I use 0 as the argument, it returns nothing. Only when I exec the sp in the same tab can I retrived the opened XML

Comment: I must admit, that I have no idea about this... The reason might be, that this approach is outdated for about 15 years... XML support was introduced with v2000 and the basic XQuery methods came into play I think with v2005. Since then the recommended approach are the [methods provided by the native XML data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-ver15). You might use a counting loop in order to call `sp_xml_removedocument` with *any* number... or restart your system if possible.

Comment: fun-fact: I just googled *sql server remove xml documents from server memory*. The [first entry is from 2005](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-remove-all-the-xml-documents-from-the-cache-memory) and it returns two suggestions: A counting loop and a server restart :-)

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks you for your answer, the server is on production, so we cannot restart it easily. The loop solution seems practical, though I think the handles may be not be unique across sessions. Anyway, I will try that solution. Thanks!

Comment: @zening.chen please let us know if this worked. This will help others with the same issue.

Comment: @Shnugo Sorry, but it doesn’t help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that the only solution to this problem is to restart the server. The error
disappeared after reboot.