# How to make sure sp_xml_removedocument is always run

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to run a query to release the space held by XML parsing created by `sp_xml_preparedocument` before the session is killed. My code is like:

```
DECLARE @idoc INT, @result XML

SELECT @result = Result
FROM XmlFieldTable

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @result

-- some query in the middle

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

I want to make sure the handle is removed before the session is killed, or the internal cache may overflow, what should I do?

I have already tried to use a try/catch statement or transaction, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Which space for XML? Which handle? Why would the session be killed without the transaction rolling back? What does @idoc represent?

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry, I have updated the content. According to [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xml-preparedocument-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the sp_xml_preparedocument will take the internal cache of the server to stored parsed XML. You can also check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316825/how-to-release-the-memory-used-to-parse-xml-field-in-sql-server/65473219#65473219) for more information.

Comment: I would recommend to use the built-in **XQuery** support instead of this old, legacy code with lots of known memory leaks and problems ......

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for recommandation, but in some situation, ```openxml``` is much faster than ```Xquery```, you may check [this answer](http://www.windows-tech.info/15/bc98c172a6f8b2d0.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have expected it to rollback the handle with a transaction on error. At least according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xml-preparedocument-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it seems to say the handle is only valid for a single session. But if it doesn't work, I suggest you report this as a bug on [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database). It does seem from [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sp_xml_removedocument-problem) that others have had the same problem.

As a workaround, catch errors client-side and check for open handles:

`SELECT document_id FROM dm_exec_xml_handles (@@spid)`

Loop through the results and pass to `sp_xml_removedocument`

You may want to close all handles periodically, even for other sessions, as the whole connection may get closed. So pass 0 to the function. You could do this as an Agent Job periodically.

If it's unclear which query is not removing handles properly, you can the find the query text with dm_exec_sql_text:

```
SELECT t.[text], h.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_xml_handles(0) h
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(h.sql_handle) t
```

Comment: If the session is killed or the query cancelled (e.g. client query timeout), no further code in the executing batch will execute, including try/catch.

Comment: @DanGuzman I know that. But a transaction should have done the trick. And if the handle is only valid for the session it stands to reason it should close the handle when the session ends.